# AAPT2 error: check logs for details AGPBI

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug]

:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
:app:processDebugManifest
C:\Users\Marco\AndroidStudioProjects\ClassFinding\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:39:9-41:45 Warning:
    Element meta-data#android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY at AndroidManifest.xml:39:9-41:45 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:31:9-33:45
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource drawable/ic_launcher_background (aka com.example.venturicompany.classfinding:drawable/ic_launcher_background) not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Marco\\AndroidStudioProjects\\ClassFinding\\app\\src\\main\\res\\mipmap-anydpi-v26\\ic_launcher.xml","position":{"startLine":2}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource drawable/ic_launcher_background (aka com.example.venturicompany.classfinding:drawable/ic_launcher_background) not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Marco\\AndroidStudioProjects\\ClassFinding\\app\\src\\main\\res\\mipmap-anydpi-v26\\ic_launcher_round.xml","position":{"startLine":2}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
:app:processDebugResources
error: failed linking file resources.
:app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
15 actionable tasks: 13 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

I tried already with "`android.enableAapt2=false`", but Android Studio doesn't allow me to disable it.

How can I navigate past this problem?

I'm using the most up to date version of Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

> {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource
>   `drawable/ic_launcher_background` (aka
>   com.example.venturicompany.classfinding:`drawable/ic_launcher_background`)
>   **not found**

It's looking for `ic_launcher_background` which couldn't be found. However, place the ic launcher icon in `/mipmap` directory. Then, use Android Studio's image Assets to create the background-foreground icon. It will create the background for ic launcher too.

However, it seems like it is defined twice too:

> AndroidManifest.xml:39:9-41:45 **duplicated** with element declared at
>   `AndroidManifest.xml`:31:9-33:45

Which needs to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

the `Mainfest.xml` is wrongful:

> Element meta-data#android.support.**PARENT_ACTIVITY** at `AndroidManifest.xml:39`
>
> duplicated with element declared at `AndroidManifest.xml:31`

Answer (score -1):

This line shows clearly

```
C:\Users\Marco\AndroidStudioProjects\ClassFinding\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:39:9-41:45 Warning:
Element meta-data#android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY at AndroidManifest.xml:39:9-41:45 duplicated with element declared at 

AndroidManifest.xml:31:9-33:45
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource drawable/ic_launcher_background (aka com.example.venturicompany.classfinding:drawable/ic_launcher_background) not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Marco\\AndroidStudioProjects\\ClassFinding\\app\\src\\main\\res\\mipmap-anydpi-v26\\ic_launcher.xml","position":{"startLine":2}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource drawable/ic_launcher_background (aka com.example.venturicompany.classfinding:drawable/ic_launcher_background) not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Marco\\AndroidStudioProjects\\ClassFinding\\app\\src\\main\\res\\mipmap-anydpi-v26\\ic_launcher_round.xml","position":{"startLine":2}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
```

Since you had not posted your manifest show i need to assume that at line number 39 duplicate element is been declared or their is something wrong with your ic launcher image
if want to set app icon then you can do by following 
1)click on new 
2)click on image asset 
3)choose your image 
4)click finish 
5)New image will be available for app icon 
6)if you had set new name then change the manifest with your new name

 
I think you had choose new image and does not change your manifest for new image(maybe this was the problem)